# PreferenceFragment is not added to Activity as expected

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-preferences, preferencefragment

I'm trying to implement `PreferenceFragment` according to the API in the Google docs, copying and pasting.

Now [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html) it says:

> You can then add this fragment to an Activity just as you would for
>   any other Fragment.

However, there is a compile-time arror at this line:

```
    // Display the fragment as the main content.
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingsFragment())
            .commit();
```

saying that:

> replace (int, android.support.v4.Fragment) in FragmentTransaction
>   cannot be aplied to (int, PrefsFragment)

where my class PrefsFragment extends PreferenceFragment.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you familiar with OOP? simply `android.preference.PreferenceFragment` not extending `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` so it cannot be used there because `android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction.replace(...)` expects `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`

Comment: Sure I know about inheritance but these support.vX frustrate me a bit, sorry. So, I copy + paste from Google's documentation and it doesn't work. Please could you give me a hint what to correct instead of asking me about OOP. thanks!

Comment: There is written in some tutorial/guide on http://d.android.com that you just can't use PreferenceFragment with v4 support library and you should build your own Activity for this (derived from FragmentActivity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently `PreferenceFragment' is not part of support library in Android, that's why you can't use it there, I found a library that solved that problem. You can find it [here](https://github.com/kolavar/android-support-v4-preferencefragment) just add it to your project and you are good to go